# If string value "X" in df1 is equal to any of the string values in df2, assign category "1" to value X in a new column in df1 in R

Tags: r, dplyr, text-classification

As part of a free text analysis and classification task, I need to assign new categories to some free text responses depending on which combinations of words they contain.

I have one tibble data frame (df1) with all the free text responses (1 column, 1 response per row) (about 17k rows), and I have a number of smaller tibbles (df2 - df10) which contain some key terms (1 column, 1 term per row).

All values are strings

I am trying to write some R code that does the following:

If string value "X" from df1 is equal to ANY of the string values in df**2**, assign string value "Category 1" to value "X" in an adjacent column in df1.

If string value "X" from df1 is equal to ANY of the string values in df**3**, assign string value "Category 2" to value "X" in an adjacent column in df1.

And so forth for df4-df10.

Below is the code I have tried so far. For the sake of simplicity, here I am only matching with df2 (category 1 terms) and assigning 'other' to everything else that doesn't match.

```
df1 %>%
  select(response) %>%
  mutate(
    category = case_when(
      df2$term %in% response ~ " Category 1",
      TRUE                ~ "other"
    )
  )
```

I get the following error when I run this:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `category`.
x Input `category` can't be recycled to size 16585.
i Input `category` is `case_when(df2$terms %in% responses~ "1", TRUE ~ "other")`.
i Input `category` must be size 16585 or 1, not 29
```

Clearly there is an issue due to different sizes of df1 and df2 and I am certain there is a straightforward solution to this, but I have been going around in circles for 2-3 hours unable to find it. I really don't want to resort to listing the actual terms rather than referring to them in a data frame.

Any help would be profoundly appreciated, please and thank you.

Comment: Try `response %in% df2$term` and see if it works. Also, can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))` and the same for `df2`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas -  your suggestion worked! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This fully vectorized function seems to do what the question asks for.

```
new_col <- function(X, String, Y){
  i <- X[[1]] %in% String
  X[[2]] <- "other"
  if(any(Y[[1]] %in% String)) X[[2]][i] <- "Category 1"
  X
}

new_col(df1, "M", df2)
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 10, TRUE))
```

Comment: How is this _fully vectorized?_ `new_col(df1, c("A", "B"), df2)` will not work